# how to solve configure kotlin setting in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I can't use android studio. i using flutter. problems.

1. updating indexes
2. configure kotlin language setting
3. looking up kotlin script definitions

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant by you use flutter not android studio.

Kotlin version is always specified in the `android/build.gradle` file. The line specifying it looks like the below:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
```

If you want to run kotlin code even from your flutter project, you should look into method channels as they offer a way for you to communicate with native code. You can check the documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels).

You can make these code edits from android studio, intellij or even vs code. I personally prefer making native edits from android studio.